# Issue with pagination in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this issue with pagination.

I have this php code here:

```
$page = $_POST['page'];
$cur_page = $page;
$page -= 1;
$per_page = 15;
$previous_btn = true;
$next_btn = true;
$first_btn = true;
$last_btn = true;
$start = $page * $per_page;
```

I have this query here:

```
$query_pag_data = 'SELECT 
    matching.date,
    matching.points,
    matching.time,
    matching.location,
    matching.epos_id,
    rbpos_epos.epos_id,
    rbpos_epos.location
FROM
    matching
LEFT JOIN
    rbpos_epos ON matching.epos_id = rbpos_epos.epos_id
WHERE
    matching.user_id = ".$id_user." LIMIT $start, $per_page';
```

I get `$start` variable is undefined. I guess it has to do with the query because if i put another query more simple it works.
Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes in your query because `$start` and `$per_page` are strings not variables

```
$query_pag_data = "SELECT 
matching.date,
matching.points,
matching.time,
matching.location,
matching.epos_id,
rbpos_epos.epos_id,
rbpos_epos.location
FROM
matching
LEFT JOIN
rbpos_epos ON matching.epos_id = rbpos_epos.epos_id
WHERE
matching.user_id = $id_user LIMIT $start, $per_page";
```